# How to put the button really at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

**I'm trying to put some buttons at the bottom of my linear layout.
The button just appears after the text,I want it to appear after the text but at the bottom.
 Here's the code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="30dip"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/test"
android:text="This is a test"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
android:textSize="16.5sp" />


 <Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:text="continue"

 android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
  />

 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LinearLayout, the only you can do is to have this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" <---
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" <---
    android:text="This is a test"
    android:textSize="16.5sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <---
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0" <---
    android:text="continue" />
```

Please check the rows with: <---

Of course the best way probably is to use a RelativeLayout and have the Button alignParentBottom like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:text="This is a test"
    android:textSize="16.5sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="continue" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: it helps but is it possible to move the button a little higher,and to right?

Comment: depending the height: you should add margin_bottom - i.e. 20dp. depending horizontal positioning: in case you need middle, you should set centerInHorizontal true, else you should set margin_left or margin_right.